# Generate a random long value that uses all of its bits

Tags: java, binary

The objective is to generate a random `long` that would use all of its 64 bit. For some reason, the far 10 bits from the right are not involved. I tried to use different bounds, created my own `pow` method that returns the power of as a `long` without using `double` and even `ThreadLocalRandom`, but non of them worked.

```
public class BitValueTest {
    public BitValueTest() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            long value = generate();
            System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(value));
        }
    }

    private long generate() {
        return getRandomValue(0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    private long getRandomValue(long min, long max) {
        return (long) ((Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BitValueTest bvt = new BitValueTest();
    }
}
```

**Here are some of the examples generated:**

110010001100000010001011110001001011010100010111110001**0000000000**
101101101100100000110010110010011110101101111000010100**0000000000**
110111110011111111101111010010010011010010100001010101**0000000000**
100001001111011101111110110101111101110100101001000010**0000000000**
101010111110110110110001100010001111101000100011111110**0000000000**
100111101000100000111000011100100010001000101101011001**0000000000**

**Sample output desired:**

1110101101010001000110011100011111011010010110000110110101101010
1111101111100111101110100000100110110101010000110111110001001101
1101111100010100100100011110110110111011010011100100100011100110
1100101110000001101100111111101011101101111101101101110010110111
1000100000000101001110100011100110110111100100011001101000110010
1100111010110000011000010000111111110010101101111000010001100001
1000000111100100100010100001111010011111001000011110010000001100

Comment: Why aren't you using `java.util.Random.nextLong()`?  Don't use doubles.

Comment: Welcome to the 53-bit mantissa of IEEE 754 double precision.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, you are correct. Furthermore, I am trying to generate the number within a range, not just randomly. I would like a way to populate, say, only the first 19 bits or only the first 56 bits.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Yes :), I figured that it dealt with precision. However, even after implementing my own `pow` method that only dealt with `long`, it still didn't work. Now, it probably is because of the `Math.random()` method that I cannot know how to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Louis Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman) and [chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic) for their comments. Based on their feedback, this is what I am looking for:

```
//import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

private long getRandomValue(long min, long max) {
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(0, max);
}
```